# Speeding up boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf

Tags: c++, boost, stream, iterator, gzip

I am new to the C++ concept of streams and want to ask for some general advice to speed up my code in [image processing](https://data.lhncbc.nlm.nih.gov/public/Visible-Human/Male-Images/70mm/fullbody/index.html). I use a stream buffer `boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf` to load and decompress the image from a file, as suggested in [this post](https://techoverflow.net/2020/01/13/how-to-decompress-gz-files-on-the-fly-in-c-using-boostiostreams/) and [another post](https://gist.github.com/yfnick/6ba33efa7ba12e93b148). The performance is not satisfactory.

The relavent code is the following:

```
template <int _NCH>
class MultiChImg {
    public: 
        ...
        ...

    private:

        std::atomic<bool> __in_operation;
        std::atomic<bool> __content_loaded;
        char  **_IMG[_NCH];
        int _W, _H;

        void dcmprss ( const std::string & file_name, bool is_decomp = true) {

            ...
            ...

            // decompress
            int counter = 0, iw = -1, ih = -1, _r = 0;
            auto _fill_ = [&](const char c){
                            _r = counter % _NCH ; // was 3 for RGB mindset
                            if ( _r == 0 ) {
                                iw++; // fast index
                                if ( iw%_W==0 ) { iw=0; ih++; } // slow index
                            }
                            _IMG[_r][_H-1-ih][iw] = c; 
                            counter ++ ;
            } ;
            auto EoS = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() ;
            // char buf[4096]; // UPDATE: improved code according to @sehe
            if ( is_decomp ) {
                // decompress 
                bio::filtering_streambuf<bio::input> input;     
                input.push( bio::gzip_decompressor() ); //  
                input.push( fstrm );
                std::basic_istream<char> inflated( &input );

                auto T3 = timing(T2, "Timing : dcmprss() prepare decomp ") ;

                // assign values to _IMG (0=>R, 1=>G, 2=>B)
                // TODO // bottleneck
                std::for_each( 
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inflated), EoS, _fill_ );
                // UPDATE: improved code according to @sehe , replace the previous two lines
                // while (inflated.read(buf, sizeof(buf))) 
                //     std::for_each(buf, buf + inflated.gcount(), _fill_);
                auto T4 = timing(T3, "Timing : dcmprss() decomp+assign ") ;

            } else {
                // assign values to _IMG (0=>R, 1=>G, 2=>B)
                // TODO // bottleneck
                std::for_each( 
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fstrm), EoS, _fill_ ); // different !
                // UPDATE: improved code according to @sehe , replace the previous two lines
                // while (fstrm.read(buf, sizeof(buf))) 
                //     std::for_each(buf, buf + fstrm.gcount(), _fill_);
                auto T3 = timing(T2, "Timing : dcmprss() assign ") ;
            }
            assert(counter == _NCH*_H*_W);

            ...
            ...
        };
...
...
}
```

The bottleneck appears to be the `for_each()` part, where I iterate the stream, either `inflated` via `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inflated)`, or `fstrm` via `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fstrm)`, to apply a lambda function `_fill_`. This lambda function transfers the bytes in the stream to the designated place in the multi-dimensional array class member `_IMG`.

UPDATE: the timing was incorrect due to memory leakage. I've corrected that.

The timing results of the above function `dcmprss()` are 450ms for a .gz file of 30MB size, 400ms for uncompressed file. I think it takes too long. So I am asking the community for some kind advice to improve.

Thanks for your time on my post!

Comment: When performance is critical you don't want to be anywhere near C++ streams. Forget it. Use `FILE *` or file descriptors, read/write them directly, and implementing your own buffering.

Comment: I don't know whether [this post](https://ayandas.me/blog-tut/2019/04/06/speeding-up-iostreams-in-c++.html) is relavent

Comment: It is somewhat relevant; that "post" appears to write an entire novel before arriving at the conclusion that I summarized in three sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use blockwise IO

```
char buf[4096];
inflated.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
std::for_each(buf, buf + inflated.gcount(), _fill_);
```

However, I also think considerable time might be wasted in `_fill_` where some dimensions are reshaped. That feels arbitrary.

Note that several libraries have the features to transparently re-index multi-dimensional data, so you may potentially save time just linearly copy the source data and accessing that:

- Boost MultiArray (allows you to specify storage order, direction and offsets: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_storage
- Boost GIL allows you to use image data directly from interleaved/planar buffers: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/gil/doc/html/design/dynamic_image.html

Comment: Amazing :-D I've tried that on my computer, 2x acceleration !     BTW: the proper code that fit my purpose should be 
````while (inflated.read(buf, sizeof(buf))) { std::for_each(buf, buf + inflated.gcount(), _fill_); } ````

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I should not rearrange the bytes to break the interleaving structure. Conceptually, the R/G/B bytes for the same pixel should be as close as possible. Later I want to use GPU to apply filters on the image data. I think the interleaving structure is better for efficiency

Comment: Indeed array reshaping by `_fill_` takes most of the time apart from decompression. Now I changed my code to adapt to the original interleaving structure and find that copy from stream cost almost nothing. The only bottleneck is decompression now :-)